# Getting opencv error in c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm try to get the error of opencv! say I have this program:

```
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>

int main (){
    cv::Mat frame;
    cv::VideoCapture cap(1); // I don't have a second videoinput device! 
    int key = 0; 

    while(key !=27){
        cap >> frame;
        cv::imshow("frame",frame);
        key = cv::waitKey(10);
    }

    cap.release();
    return 0;
}
```

when I run this program I  get in the console this message :

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in unknown functi
on, file ..\..\..\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp, line 261
```

My question is how can I  get this message and save it in a string for every error that I get!
and if it'S possible escaping the program crash!

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It uses C++ exceptions. See [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html#error-handling) in the doc for more.

```
try
{
    ... // call OpenCV
}
catch( cv::Exception& e )
{
    const char* err_msg = e.what();
    std::cout << "exception caught: " << err_msg << std::endl;
}
```

---

A `CV_Assert` in the OpenCV code is a macro which calls the OpenCV function `error`. That function can be seen [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/system.cpp). It will always print the error text on stderr unless you don't have the `customErrorCallback` set. You do that via `cvRedirectError`, see [here](http://opencv.jp/opencv-2.2_org/c/core_utility_and_system_functions_and_macros.html#redirecterror).

Comment: thanks for your answer! it works , is there anyway to disable the output of the error message bellow ?

Comment: Just remove the `std::cout`? You can put it inside a file instead.

Comment: no it doesn't work ! the output happens in cv::imshow()  because the frame is pointing to NULL value

Comment: @Engine: You can do that via `cvRedirectError`. I extended my answer.

Comment: @Albert Hey, my `cvWriteFrame` routine returns a 0 (meaning it failed, I have observed it returns 1 when I actually was able to write a video). But, I need to extract verbose error messages. It raises no exception and  tried redirecting the `stderr` to `stdout` from the command line itself to no success. Can you help me with using `cvRedirectError` in `PyOpenCV`?Documentation has no help!

Comment: @activatedGeek: I did a short Google search and found [this](http://code.google.com/p/pyopencv/source/browse/trunk/codegen/cxcore_h.py?r=347). There is a TODO written on `cvRedirectError`. So I guess that's not supported yet. You should better ask and report the PyOpenCV people about that (mailinglist or so).

Answer (score -1):

You have to check whether OpenCV function calls in your code is successfully executed or not. Then you can understand the exact problem. Here is the modified code.

```
int main (){
    cv::Mat frame;
    cv::VideoCapture cap(1); // I don't have a second videoinput device! 

    if ( !cap.isOpened() )  // if not success, exit program
    {
         cout << "Cannot open the video cam" << endl;
         return -1;
    }

    int key = 0; 

    while(key !=27){
        bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from video

         if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
        {
            cout << "Cannot read the frame from video cam" << endl;
            break;
        }
        cv::imshow("frame",frame);
        key = cv::waitKey(10);
    }

    cap.release();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the problem isn't getting the program running, but having a way to save opencv error messages