# Segmentation Fault in some OpenCV Functions

Tags: c++, opencv, segmentation-fault, ros

I'm using `OpenCV 4.7.0` built from source in Ubuntu `20.04` and I'm getting a segmentation fault `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` while calling a Gaussian Blur or `getStructuringElement` in c++:

```cpp
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

// some code to:
// read the image, 
// convert it to grayscale and filter it (median filter)

// type2str: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17820615
std::string ty =  type2str( filtered_img.type() );
printf("Matrix: %s %dx%d \n", ty.c_str(),
 filtered_img.cols, filtered_img.rows );

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/19488679
try
    {   
        std::cout << "Before Gaussian Filter" << std::endl;
        cv::GaussianBlur(filtered_img, filtered_img,
                          cv::Size(3, 3), 0);
    }
    catch( cv::Exception& e )
    {
        const char* err_msg = e.what();
        std::cout << "exception caught: " 
        << err_msg << std::endl;
    }
// same issue with `getStructuringElement`
try
    {
        cv::Mat dil_kernel = cv::getStructuringElement( dilation_type,
                       cv::Size( 2*dial_k + 1, 2*dial_k+1 ),
                       cv::Point( dial_k, dial_k ) );
    }
    catch( cv::Exception& e )
    {
        const char* err_msg = e.what();
        std::cout << "exception caught: " << err_msg << std::endl;
    }
```

#### output:

```
Matrix: 8UC1 371x442 
Before Gaussian Filter
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I have seen the image `cv::imshow('img', filtered_img)` before passing it to the Gaussian Filter and it seems to be OK, and I have passed this image to a median filter and worked properly, can you please tell me how can I solve this issue please? thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you're allowed to use the same image for the source *and* destination arguments to `cv:: GaussianBlur`?

Comment: @G.M. I have tried to use another one as an output `g_filtered_img` but that didn't solve the problem!

Comment: Can you show the full code? Where does the image come from? What else are you doing? What is type2str?

Comment: Can you add a std::cout << "After Gaussian Filter" << std::endl;?

Comment: Which values have dilation_type and dial_k?

Comment: Can you try to use an image with even size in both dimensions? E.g. 372x442 instead of 371x442?

Comment: [mre] please. I don't see you defining `filtered_img` anywhere

Comment: @Micka the problem turns to be that Multiple `OpenCV` versions are installed on my machine `warning: libopencv_imgproc.so.407, needed by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.4.7.0, may conflict with libopencv_imgproc.so.4.2`

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz the problem is not related to the code itself, the problem is CMake is using an older version of `OpenCV` due to multiple versions are installed.

Comment: I couldn't have guessed that (without seeing that warning in the output). good to know that presents as a segfault.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz removing all `OpenCV` versions and recompiling from source solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing ROS implies installing older version `4.2` of `OpenCV` library and headers, so even if I specify in `CMakeLists.txt` that the required version is `4.7` when I print the used version (comes from the header file) I see `4.2` which made a mismatch between the used library `4.7` and the headers `4.2`.

**The Solution:**

- to specify the required version of `OpenCV` from `CMake` in addition to the path to he header files (*manually*),
- or to remove the `OpenCV 4.2` installed by default with ROS.